# HTML button hyperlink not opening other files

Tags: html, css

I have a "html home page" and I want the button to direct to other local files in the browser. This works fine with hyperlinks but I got code for custom buttons that I want to use but they aren't allowing me to open local files just links.
Code:

```html
<html>
<body style="background-color:rgb(48, 45, 45)">
<font color="white">
<font color="#4CAF50">
<head>
<style>
b {
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(252, 239, 0);
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 15px;
border-radius: 8px;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Science</h1>
<b href="file:///D:\School Project\Physics.html">Physics</b>
```

[image: Preview of the html code]

Comment: Insert your code inside the body. A bold element is not an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: use some `a` tags as usual and style them the way you want them to look like (probably like the yellow buttons in the screenshot).

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to make a link arround your button, you could use this code:

```
<a href="file:///D:\School Project\Physics.html"><b>Physics</b></a>
```

Comment: Thank You, For anyone finding this there will be and underline under physics so do `<a href="file:///D:\School Project\Physics.html" style="text-decoration: none;"><b>Physics</b></a><b` to remove the underline

Comment: Alternatively you can get rid of the `b` tag by just setting the style you defined to `a` tag and using `<a href="file:///D:\School Project\Physics.html">Physics</a>`.
For bigger project I advice you to use class and id for selecting elements in CSS.

Comment: If my answer helped don't hesitate to mark as resolved

Answer (score -1):

Use the `document.href.location`
For example:

```html
<button onclick="goToHomePage">Click Me</button>
<script>
  function goToHomePage() {
    document.location.href = ''; // put the document location in between the quotation marks
  }
</script>
```

Or use `<a>` elements
For example:

```html
<a href="#">Click Me</a> <!-- put the document location in between the quotation marks instead of the '#'-->
```